# Searching thru an array case-insensitivly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, case-insensitive

I have an Array of different transactions and I need to search thru the array for different names of businesses. I need a search method that can find these 3 names.

```
#<Transaction:0xdf38664 @id="kZB3Y63qBvSDK5eM8K3ESqQDLbpzEZfj19wje", @account="ODaJY8Jza5cBgj7XDg3euOoR7ogrjeCMQZPed", @amount=189.85, @name="DIRECTV", @meta={"is_risky"=>false, "location"=>{}}, @location=nil, @pending=false, @score={"location"=>{}, "name"=>1}, @type={"primary"=>"place"}, @category=["Service", "Cable"], @category_id="18009000">]
```

My search right now is this:

```
@transactions = @user.transactions.find_all { |t| t.name.include? 'comcast') }
```

But this only finds the name case specifically

The transactions may have names like any of these:
    "name": "DirecTV";
    "name": "directv";
    "name": "DIRECTV"

I need a method that will find all 3 of this names with that same name search.

I thought casecmp but that only returns a number not the array item. Unless there is a way to use casecmp to return the transaction array but I dont see how.

Comment: Downcase it, then compare?

Comment: What database backend are you using?

Comment: MongoidDB is my database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is an ActiveRecord model with relationships, you should treat it as such for performance purposes

```
@user.transactions.where "lower(name) IN (?)", ["comcast", "directv", "somethingelse"]
```

If it really is an array, you could do

```
@user.transactions.find_all {|t| t.name.downcase =~ /comcast|directv|somethingelse/ }
```

Comment: By the way @SupremeA the second way relies on regex. It's always a good idea to have at least cursory knowledge about them

Comment: Ok I will look into it; although I hear people say regex is slower but I am not concerned about speed